# Switching Xfce workspaces with remote desktop

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop, xfce

I use 5 workspaces with Xfce. I have two monitors. On one of the two screens of Workspace 1, I run Remmina for remote desktop to remote into a windows machine.

Problem is, when I am working in Windows, my Xfce keyboard shortcuts stop working. So, I cannot do `Ctrl + Alt + right/left` to switch workspaces. I have to manually drag my mouse to the second screen of my workspace, which then activates Xfce keyboard, and now I can switch to another workspace using keyboard.

Could you please suggest me a way to switch workspaces using Keyboard when working on remote desktop (Remmina)

Comment: does putting remmina to full screen mode solve the problem?

Comment: @Serge Yes, I am running Remmina in full screen mode

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Remmina, it seems that you can decide whether it should grab the keyboard or not. See [this thread in SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57725/remmina-doesnt-eat-keys)